Problems with the "select" - Feature of dplyr (in R)
So my problem is as follows:
I'm currently working on a project with the Allbus2021 survey and I want to select certain types of questions for my project.
These specific variables all start with "fr" OR "vm" OR "im" OR "ma" - i.e. "fr07".
So my way was to use the select command with the addition of "starts_with" - as seen in my code below:
befdat = df_21_wom %>% 
  select(starts_with(c("fr","vm","im","mi","ma")))

Unfortunately I get an error message stating the following

Error in select(., starts_with(c("fr", "vm", "im", "mi", "ma")))
unused argument (starts_with(c("fr", "vm", "im", "mi", "ma")))

Does anybody has an solution for my Problem?
Kind regards!

What packages do you have loaded? Maybe try dplyr::select to see if there's another select function that was defined elsewhere. That will make sure you are using the dplyr version. You can run conflicts(detail = TRUE) to check for naming conflicts. Running iris %>% select(starts_with(c("Sepal", "Petal"))) works fine for me

Thank you for your quick Response! I now looked at my logfile and tested the test command with the iris dataset. Apparently my Problem is the dplyr Package which is "not available" for the R Version I'm working with.. - I'm working with the 4.3.1 Version..

did you run install.packages("dplyr")? That package should absolutely be available.

I just ran into a new problem: Apparently there is a problem with dplyr in general. I'm using pacman to install all necessary packages and somehow everything gets installed except dplyer - sending me the error message, which i stated above.... I'm opening a new Thread - Thank you again!

Make sure you as spelling the package name correctly. Show exactly the command you are running and copy/paste the error messages exactly as they appear.

Thank you for your help! I double checked everything and as you already assumed: There is an conflict between two packages. Now everything works! :)
